# how to extract each characters from a image?with using this code

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

i have to extract each characters from a image here i am uploading the code it is segmenting the horizontal lines but not able to segment the each characters along with the horizontal line segmentation loop. some1 please help to correct the code
this is the previous code:

```
%%horizontal histogram
H = sum(rotatedImage, 2);
darkPixels = H < 100; % Threshold
% label
[labeledRegions, numberOfRegions] = bwlabel(darkPixels);
fprintf('Number of regions = %d\n', numberOfRegions);
% Find centroids
measurements = regionprops(labeledRegions, 'Centroid');
% Get them into an array
allCentroids = [measurements.Centroid];
xCentroids = int32(allCentroids(1:2:end));
yCentroids = int32(allCentroids(2:2:end));
% Now you can just crop out some line of text you're interested in, into a separate image:
hold off;
plotLocation = 8;
for band = 1 : numberOfRegions-1 
    row1 = yCentroids(band);        
    row2 = yCentroids(band+1);        
    thisLine = rotatedImage(row1 : row2, :);
    subplot(7, 2, plotLocation)
    imshow(thisLine, [])
    %% Let's compute and display the histogram.
    verticalProjection = sum(thisLine, 2);
    set(gcf, 'NumberTitle', 'Off') 
    t = verticalProjection;
    t(t==0) = inf;
    mayukh=min(t);
    % 0 where there is background, 1 where there are letters
    letterLocations = verticalProjection > mayukh; 
    % Find Rising and falling edges
    d = diff(letterLocations);
    startingRows = find(d>0);
    endingRows = find(d<0);
    % Extract each region
    y=1;
    for k = 1 : length(startingRows)
        % Get sub image of just one character...
        subImage = thisLine(:, startingRows(k):endingRows(k)); 
        [L,num] = bwlabel(subImage);
        for z= 1 : num
            bw= ismember( L, z);
            % Construct filename for this particular image.
            baseFileName = sprintf('templates %d.png', y);
            y=y+1;
            % Prepend the folder to make the full file name.
            fullFileName = fullfile('C:\Users\Omm\Downloads\', baseFileName);
            % Do the write to disk.
            imwrite(bw, fullFileName);
            pause(2);
            imshow(bw);
            pause(5)
        end;
        y=y+2;
    end;
    plotLocation = plotLocation + 2;
end
```

but not segmenting the whole lines

Comment: what is this question about? Keep in mind that we don't know what you are doing. You should write question so that a new user gets a complete picture of what's going on.

Comment: @ Parag S. Chandakkar  now i have corrected now could you please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply use [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) with `'Image'` property?

```
img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpYa5.png');  %// read the image
bw = img(:,:,1) > 128;  %// conver to mask
```

Use some minor morphological operations to handle spurious pixels

```
dbw = imdilate(bw, ones(3)); 
lb = bwlabel(dbw).*bw;  %// label each character as a connected component
```

Now you can use `regionprops` to get each image

```
st = regionprops( lb, 'Image' );
```

Visualize the results

```
figure;
for ii=1:numel(st),  
    subplot(4,5,ii);
    imshow(st(ii).Image,'border','tight');
    title(num2str(ii));
end
```

[image]

Comment: i used this but it's not working and showing a blank figure as a output :(